# Assigning object created in function to member variable

Tags: c++, object, scope, member

So I'm fairly new to C++ and all the memory management that comes along with it.

My problem is that I create an object in the function *expand* and then assign said object to a member variable in another object of the same class (the class is a binary tree where its data is an *InVec* object).

After the function runs, the memory location of *m_left* and *m_right* for a given *SPnode* are the same, however the dereferenced values are junk.

I'm almost certain that this is due to the *InVec* and *SPnode* objects going out of scope and being destroyed, thus yielding pointers *m_left* and *m_right* which point to junk.

My question is: How do I create an object inside a function, assign it to a member variable and not have it destroyed when the function terminates? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere (I'm not even sure how to phrase it).

Here's my code:

```
void expand(SPnode &ASP)
{
    if (!(ASP.isLeaf())) return;

    int axis(ASP.m_box.getWidthAxis());
    Interval width(ASP.m_box.getWidth());

    InVec lowerInVec(lower(ASP.m_box, width, axis));
    InVec upperInVec(upper(ASP.m_box, width, axis));


    SPnode leftChild(lowerInVec);
    std::cout << &leftChild << "\n";

    SPnode rightChild(upperInVec);
    std::cout << &rightChild << "\n";


    ASP.m_left = &leftChild;
    std::cout << (ASP.m_left) << "\n";

    ASP.m_right = &rightChild;
    std::cout << (ASP.m_right) << "\n";
}
```

I apologize if this code is bad form or if I'm breaking some important rules - any constructive criticism would also be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the relevant code for Interval, InVec and SPnode:

```
// The Interval class is the base object on which all other classes in this
// module are built. Its implementation is intuitive, as all mathematical
// operations that are relevant for nonlinear image computation are given
// as overloaded operators (i.e. intervalA + intervalB returns the expected
// result from basic interval arithmetic).
class Interval
{
private:

    // infimum (lower bound) of interval
    double m_inf;

    //supremum (upper bound) of interval
    double m_sup;

public:
    Interval(double inf, double sup): m_inf(inf), m_sup(sup) {}

    // getter member functions, where getLen returns the length of the interval
    // and getMidpt returns the midpoint
    double getInf() const {return m_inf;}
    double getSup() const {return m_sup;}
    double getLen() const {return m_sup - m_inf;}
    double getMidpt() const {return (m_inf + m_sup)/2.0;}


// --- Headers -----------------------------------------------------------------

    // determines if a double is in the interval
    bool containsVal(double val) const;

    // determines if another interval is contained in the interval
    bool contains(const Interval &other) const;

    // performs scalar multiplication on the interval
    Interval scalarMul(double scal) const;


    // operator overloading - the specifics of interval arithmetic can be found
    // in a book or online
    friend Interval operator+(const Interval &intA, const Interval &intB);
    friend Interval operator-(const Interval &intA, const Interval &intB);
    friend Interval operator*(const Interval &intA, const Interval &intB);
    friend bool operator==(const Interval &intA, const Interval &intB);
    friend bool operator!=(const Interval &intA, const Interval &intB);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Interval &intA);


    friend void expand(SPnode &ASP);
    friend InVec lower(const InVec &box, const Interval &width, int axis);
    friend InVec upper(const InVec &box, const Interval &width, int axis);
};

class InVec
{
private:

    // this is a vector containing the Interval objects that make up the InVec 
    // object
    std::vector<Interval> m_intervals;

public:

    InVec(std::vector<Interval> intervals): m_intervals(intervals) {}

    // returns m_intervals
    std::vector<Interval> getIntervals() const {return m_intervals;}

    // returns the interval at given axis (i.e. index) in m_intervals
    Interval getInterval(int axis) const {return m_intervals.at(axis);}

    // sets the interval at given axis to given Interval object
    void setInterval(int axis, const Interval &intA)
    {m_intervals.at(axis) = intA;}


// --- Headers -----------------------------------------------------------------

    // determines if another InVec object is contained in this InVec object
    bool contains(const InVec &IVB) const;

    // returns the length of the largest Interval object in m_intervals - note
    // that it is necessary to compute this first, before the actual largest
    // Interval can be determined
    double getWidthSize() const;

    // returns the Interval in m_intervals with the longest length 
    // (i.e. the width)
    Interval getWidth() const;


    // returns the axis (i.e. index) on which the width occurs
    double getWidthAxis() const;


    // operator overloading
    friend InVec operator+(const InVec &IVA, const InVec &IVB);
    friend InVec operator-(const InVec &IVA, const InVec &IVB);
    friend InVec operator*(const InVec &IVA, const InVec &IVB);
    friend bool operator==(const InVec &intA, const InVec &intB);
    friend bool operator!=(const InVec &intA, const InVec &intB);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const InVec &IVA);


    friend void expand(SPnode &ASP);
    friend InVec lower(const InVec &box, const Interval &width, int axis);
    friend InVec upper(const InVec &box, const Interval &width, int axis);

};

class SPnode
{
private:

    InVec m_box;

    // left and right children of this SPnode object - note that these must be
    // pointers in order to use them in the definition of the class, otherwise 
    // SPnode would have an inifinite definition
    SPnode* m_left;
    SPnode* m_right;

public:

    SPnode(InVec box): m_box(box), m_left(NULL), m_right(NULL) {}


    // getters and setters
    InVec getBox() const {return m_box;}
    SPnode* getLeft() const {return m_left;}
    SPnode* getRight() const {return m_right;}
    void setBox(const InVec box) {m_box = box;}
    void setLeft(SPnode* const p_node) {m_left = p_node;}
    void setRight(SPnode* const p_node) {m_right = p_node;}

    bool isLeaf() const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const SPnode &ASP);
    friend void expand(SPnode &ASP);
    friend InVec lower(const InVec &box, const Interval &width, int axis);
    friend InVec upper(const InVec &box, const Interval &width, int axis);  
};
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `SPnode` and `InVec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your childs as pointers and use the new operator to dynamically allocate them, like this:

```
SPnode * leftChild = new SPnode(lowerInVec);
```

And the assign it to the object member variable like this:

```
ASP.m_left = leftChild;
```

Also you should declare m_left as a SPnode pointer, like this:

```
SPNode * m_left;
```

Do the same to the right one.

Ps.: Before understanding smart pointers you should understand pointers, which are allocated using the new operator.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'm not completely familiar with the _new_ operator so I'll have to read up on it.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to dynamically allocate your nodes. And than you'd need to manage that memory with smart pointer - most likely, `std::unique_ptr`.

Your code would be something like:

```
ASP.m_left = std::make_unique<SPnode>(lowerInVec);
```

That is in suggestion that SPNode constructor does not try to keep the reference (or an address) to it's argument. If it does, said argument would have to be dynamically allocated as well.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll have to do some reading on smart pointers.